# Ubuntu MATE Pi not connecting to monitor?

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu

I just flashed a MicroSD card with Ubuntu MATE. I booted up my Pi 3 Model B with it and the monitor is just showing a black screen. The monitor looks like it is connected to the Pi, because it is on and it does not say "No Input". It is connected to the Pi with an HDMI to DVI cable. I booted up the Pi with a NOOBS card and it connects to the monitor just fine so i think it is a problem on the SD. The monitor is a Samsung Model T220 22". Does anyone know what is going on here? Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu Mate 16.04 won't boot on a Raspberry Pi 3B+.

Answer (score 0):

Can you still SSH into the Pi?
If so, follow these steps:

1. Type `sudo nano /boot/config.txt`
2. You should see a line that says, `# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output #hdmi_force_hotplug=1`, delete the `#` in front of the `hdmi_force_hotplug=1`, then press CTRL + X to save the file.
3. type `sudo reboot` to reboot the Pi.

I had the same issue when attempting to use Kodi OSMC on my Vizio Smart TV.
If this does not fix the issue, I would suggest contacting the manufacturer of the monitor.
You may notice that if this does fix the issue, the monitor may turn to black after a few minutes of being turned on, then it switches back on. This is how you know it is working.

I found the solution in [this](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/hdmi-audio-help/7988/3) thread.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Exchange! Just to be sure, you're suggesting inserting the SD card into another computer, mounting the `boot` partition, and then editing the `config.txt` file? If so, could you please specify this before instructions 1, 2, and 3 to avoid any confusion?

Comment: No, I asked initially if the user could access the Pi via SSH.
If he could, I then suggested following my steps 1, 2, and 3.
At no point did I mention to insert the SD card into another computer.

Comment: Hi! i am the original asker of the question. I figured out that the HDMI port on my Pi was broken and that was the cause of the problem.